# polymer web-component not registering

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

So a disclaimer, I am new to Polymer, web components, Node and Express. Today is my first time using all of these technologies and I tried to avoid asking simple questions, but I can not find an answer to this question anywhere.

I am trying to serve a static HTML page that renders a simple custom element.

I believe everything with node is working fine as there are no errors in the console, and all of my resources are visible under the 'sources' tag of the chrome-dev tools. However, my custom element seems to remain unregistered. It shows up in the dom, but it has no children and its height/width are 0. Everything else on the page renders fine.

This is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

  <title>blah</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <link rel="import" href="/web_components/my-element.html">
  <my-element></my-element> 

  <h1> Hello Polymer? </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is `my-element.html`

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <div>This is my shadow DOM!</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Here's a console screen shot:

[image]

This is a screen shot of my server-side code, which also depicts my file-structure on the left. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using 0.5 syntax with the 1.0 version of Polymer. Check out the [Quick Tour](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html) to get started. For example, you should use `<dom-module>` instead of `<polymer-element>`.

Comment: gah! thats it. Thank you